# Laravel 5.3 - Validation rule min and required_if issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

So in a `Request` we have some validation, where the `type` field will be `review`, which means the `body` field has to have a minimum of 6 characters.

```
public function rules(){
     return [
       'type' => 'required|in:star_rating,review',
       'body' => 'required_if:type,review|min:6'
     ];
 }
```

However, the issue is that when the `type` is `star_rating`, I get an error that `The body must be at least 6 characters.`

This should not happen, since the body is optional and ONLY should be required and validated with `min:6` if `type` is `review`. I can't seem to figure out why it runs the `min:6` validation on it even if the `type` is `star_rating`.

Any idea how to get it to work as intended?

Comment: I suppose it would be due to `required_if` only applies the `required` rule, _not_ to the `min` rule. Seems you're looking to ignore the `min` rule too, which `required_if` doesn't apply to. You're likely looking for [conditionally adding rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) which allows you to define `sometimes` when a given condition is true. Check out the `closure` based validation in that link above, it'll handle what you need!

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how to integrate the code in the link into the `Request` which has the two standard functions `authorize` and `rules` Any idea how to correctly integrate it into the `Request`?

Comment: Added an answer that should help, too much to type in comments. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without seeing more of your logic, I can't be certain how you want to proceed. But the concept below should get you going.

It [conditionally adds rules](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#conditionally-adding-rules) according to parameters you define. In your case, it only requires `body` if `type` is `review`, and also applies the `min` rule of `6` characters if again, `type` is `review`.

```
use Validator;

// Static rules that don't change
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'type' => 'required|in:star_rating,review'
]);

// Conditional rules that do change
$v->sometimes('body', 'required|min:6', function ($input) {
    return $input->type === 'review';
});

// Validator failed? Return back with errors/input
if ($validator->fails()) {
    return back()->withErrors($validator)
                 ->withInput();
}

// Proceed however you'd like with request
```

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue (in laravel 5.4), and what I don't understand both in the docs and in your answer, is : where to put this code ?

Is it in the FormRequest file ? As Wonka says, it has only two methods, `authorise` `rules` and I don't get how to implement this in one of those methods

Is it in my controller ? If yes, It's a little annoying as I am refactoring my controller to put the validation process in a Request.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and CamelCase's answer works well !
But I had to put my validation logic back to my controller as my attempt was to put this validation logic in a `Request`.

So here's another solution with conditionnal rules in the `Request` that works in Laravel 5.4

```
public function rules()
    {
        // general rules
        $rules = [
            'type' => 'required|in:star_rating,review',                
        ];

        // conditional rules
        if($this->input('type') == 'review'){
            $rules['body'] = 'required | min:6';
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```